# Apache mod_rewrite 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a dynamic subdomain and I am having great difficulty, I keep getting 500 Internal Server Error

So for example the actual domain should be

http://www.parameterToBePassed.domain.com/

which should point/redirect

http://www.domain.com/shopping/gatename/parameterToBePassed

However when I access this URL I get an Internal Server Error (500), any ideas?

The vhost.conf holds

```
ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com *.domain.com

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/shopping/gatename/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am using, Redhat Linux, With Plesk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I have answered a post like that not so long ago, although here the situation differs a little)

Say someone goes to `a.domain.com`. This matches both conditions.

The main problem: your rewrite rule matches an empty input...

So, `a.domain.com` goes through the rule and becomes `a.domain.com/shopping/gatename/`.

And then it goes back to the server *again*, and matches *again* both conditions. The URL becomes `a.domain.com/shopping/gatename/shoppin/gatename/`.

Have you noticed? It substitute with the value of the request, not what you captured in your second RewriteCond, and there lies your other problem.

You *can* reuse groups captured by `RewriteCond` but they are preceded with `%`, not `$`. Hence, what you want really is this (with full regex metacharacters etc plus anchors):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
# Non capturing group for "www." if present: it is of no interest
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/shopping/gatename/%1/$1 [L] # Note the %!
```